# Why unused embedding vector changed after backward?

Tags: pytorch, embedding

I'm partially fine-tuning a embedding matrix (just for some particular index). But in backward phase, other embeddings which is not expected to be modified are changed.

Here is an example:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

embeds = nn.Embedding(10, 3)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(params=embeds.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=1e-6)
indexes = torch.tensor([1,2,3])  # expected to finetune
bce_loss = nn.BCELoss()

optim.zero_grad()
loss = bce_loss(embeds(indexes).sum(dim=-1), torch.zeros(3))
loss.backward()
optim.step()
```

I only want to finetune 1st, 2nd, 3rd embeddings, but after backward, the entire embedding matrix is changed. Why? And how to solve this problem? THX!

Answer (score 0):

The change in embedding matrix after `optim.step()` is not entirely due to the loss you defined (i.e. BCELoss). You are overlooking the other part of the loss that is being implicitely defined due to the `weight_decay` parameter in your optimizer. When you supply a non-zero weight decay, it adds a second commponent to the loss that is over *all parameters* of the model. Just turn that off

```
optim = torch.optim.Adam(..., weight_decay=0.)
```

and you will see expected result.

Comment: Nice! It works!